# Directive exportAs doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I faced with a problem when try to use exportAs property od Directive decorator:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *repeat="5; let i = index; let odd = odd;" [class.odd]="odd" #r="repeatDir">{{i}} - Hello World!</div>
```

**repeat.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[repeat]',
  exportAs: 'repeatDir'
})
export class RepeatDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() repeat: number;

  constructor(private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.repeat; i++) {
      this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef, {
        index: i,
        odd: i % 2 === 1
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this example I got the error:
[image]

Comment: Because you applied it to the element which is a child of your structural directive

Comment: Sorry, just 1 clarification: could you give an example how correctly to use exportAs? I tried an attribute directive and got the same error...(

Comment: Look at this example. It's the same what you're doing https://ng-run.com/edit/ZyYOu1FdglT058PwuQFt

Comment: `<ng-template [repeat]="5" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" #r="repeatDir">` should work for you. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12121